# Unnecessary type casting?

Tags: java, oop, tdd

I am reading this [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) and there is a code example which seems confusing to me, the confusing part of the fragment I am describing below:

```
private Hashtable rates = new Hashtable();

void addRate(String from, String to, int rate) {
  rates.put(new Pair(from , to), new Integer(rate)); // Pair is a value object.
}

int rate(String from, String to) {
  Integer rate = (Integer) rates.get(new Pair(from, to)); // The confusing part.
  return rate.intValue();
}
```

Why the author needs to type cast while getting the value from `HashTable` if the value was already of type `Integer`?

Comment: `Hashtable` returns Object, so the casting is necessary.

Comment: That must be an old book; those are [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: With such an untyped hashtable, any type of object could be added to it, not just Integers

Comment: @ElliottFrisch oh, but that is the only good book I found on TDD, what should be correct code then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), default usage of `Hashtable` creates a hash map where the key is an object of type `Object` and also a value which is of type `Object`.

Although you are placing integer values, when you are reading them back, you have no guarantee of what the object is, thus you will need to type cast it. Since what you are placing can be casting to an integer, the casting does not fail.

An alternative which does not require casting would be to use the generic version.

Comment: Or better, use the newer `Map` type instead of Hashtable, which is basically legacy at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need typecasting if only you declared hashtable mentioning you will store integers in it.

Eg -

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> numbers = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
numbers.put("one", 1);
numbers.put("two", 2);
numbers.put("three", 3);

Integer n = numbers.get("two");
if (n != null) {
    System.out.println("two = " + n);
}
```

Edit:

Didn't notice the book OP mentioned is quite old when generics were not there in Java.

So advice to OP - Refer to latest resources.

Comment: book was published in 2002 which pre-dates generics by a bit.

Answer (score 0):

something to you:

you are reading [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321146530):

> Product Details Paperback: 240 pages Publisher: Addison-Wesley
> Professional; 1 edition (November 18, 2002) Language: English ISBN-10:
> 0321146530 ISBN-13: 978-0321146533 Product

## for that date, that could be either [java 1.3 or maybe at the most java 1.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)

So that must be a really old book, actual java [HashTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) uses generics and the [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method returns the class parameter and not a Object class

> public V get(Object key)

so for the new java version no cast is needed...

---

please use new literature, technology changes really fast... we are almost here with java 8 and looking forward for the 9th

---

## Edit:

I've found what I was looking for:

in java 4:

[HashTable class](https://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/) get method returns an object and cast is necessary...
[image]

but in java 7 for example:

[HashTable class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) get method returns an V Type and cast is NOT necessary...

[image]

Comment: Generic types were added in Java 5.